# How to print information dynamically from yaml generated dictionary?

Tags: yaml, python-3.6

maybe have I a trivial issue, but i can't go through. I'm relatively new in python, please, if you can, help me out.
I have a yaml file for configuration. Something like this:

```
---
prod:
  app1:
    hosts:
      - host1
      - host2
  app2:
    hosts:
      - host3
      - host4
```

I would like to use this yaml to generate a menu. My problem is that, I can not print detailed information from the data structure.
As I know, if I read in the yaml, the result will be a dictionary.:

```
def read_env():
    with open("env.yaml", 'r') as stream:
        try:
            data = yaml.load(stream)
            return data
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)
        finally:
            stream.close()
```

If I manually print something out, that's ok:

```
print(data["prod"]["app1"]["hosts"])
```

This line of code will print us the "host1, host2".
How can I do something like this?

```
mylist = []
mylist.append(prod)
mylist.append(app2)
mylist.append(hosts)

print(data[mylist])
```

Thank your answers in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found a simple solution:

```
mylist = ["prod", "app1", "hosts"]
tmp = ""
for i, item in enumerate(mylist):
  if(i == 0):
    tmp = data[item]
  else:
    tmp = tmp[item]
print(tmp)
```

This code will give me back the "host1, host2", and also able to handle dynamically.

If you have a cleaner solution, please let me know.
Thank in advance!